# Can you redirect a tag wiki to another tag's wiki?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

We have folks submitting under tags PowerShell, PowerShell-v1.0 and PowerShell-v2.0.  I think it would make the most sense to just have PowerShell-v* refer to the base PowerShell tag wiki.  It could include sections discussing differences between 1.0 and 2.0.  However I don't know if this is possible.  If it is possible, how do you go about doing it?

Comment: Could you just add a link?

Comment: Sure. I thought that there might be some way to specify that the tags were synonymous though and that clicking on the synonym would just take you to the base level tag's wiki page.

Comment: Well, if the tags were synonymous you would mark them as synonymous, but you mean the tag wikis should be identical

Comment: Well PowerShell and PowerShell-v1.0 are pretty much synonymous. PowerShell-v2.0 has new features but shares a lot of the same wiki information ie the base level stuff except for the new 2.0 features.  I was thinking that the wiki for PowerShell-v1.0 should just be the same wiki the PowerShell tag has.  But I've put in a link on that wiki which is an OK way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I wrote the initial versions of the [make] and [makefile] tag wikis I *only* put a link in the [makefile] wiki (pointing to the [make] wiki).

'Cause I'm lazy and really prefer [make].

Comment: It appears that is the only mechanism to provide a common wiki for similar (even synonymous) tags.