# PowerShell tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Do we really need a PowerShell tag for every version of PowerShell?

It seems like a lot of questions are tagged PowerShell and also PowerShell-v1.0, PowerShell-v2.0, and PowerShell-v3.0.

1. Tag [powershell-v1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v1.0) : 76 questions
2. Tag [powershell-v2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v2.0) : 1,198 questions
3. Tag [powershell-v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell-v3.0) : 176 questions
4. Tag [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell): 9,035 questions

A similar question though relating to [wiki's on PowerShell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62452/can-you-redirect-a-tag-wiki-to-another-tags-wiki). I don't know enough about PowerShell to categorize them according to their nuances. If you take for example, C#, it has separate tags for different versions of C#, but most questions are tagged C# only, not by their version.

Comment: There are pretty major differences between the versions.

Comment: @JNK: Ok, but it seems like it is carte blanche labeling.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, most of the questions SHOULD be tagged with a version.  The nature of PS is that a lot of people don't outright know what version they are using, it's not like you installed SQL Server 2008r2 and get a splash screen.  I think there is utility in keeping all the tags as they are.

Comment: @JNK: But labeling with every version makes sense too? Or all four tags?

Comment: No that doesn't make sense, but that doesn't mean you need to get rid of them.  Keeping the tags and using them accurately are separate issues.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Closing a question does *not* bump it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to your **stated** question

> Do we really need a PowerShell tag for every version of PowerShell?

...is YES.  There are very large differences between the various versions, and a 3.0 solution may not work with 2.0 may not work with 1.0.

The answer to your **implied** question

> Are these tags being used correctly?

...is probably NO but that is separate from the issue of keeping the tags.  There aren't currently a ton of PS questions so it shouldn't be hard to clean them up.

There ARE cases where you may want to conceivably use all the tags, i.e. you have a wide range of installs you need something to work for and it needs to be universal.  I imagine most of the extra tagging arises from people not knowing what version they are on.